Freegpt-webui python displays "No matching distribution found for mailgw_temporary_email" when installing
complete error message
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mailgw_temporary_email (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mailgw_temporary_email

I tried searching for this package in pip, but it didn't exist at all.
Now the installation is stuck, is there any solution?

Note that Freegpt-webui has been archived and has not been maintained since September 2023. For a package that uses an API, this is bad, as API's can change and it seems like that it is already not working anymore, see https://github.com/ramon-victor/freegpt-webui/issues/212
mailgw_temporary_email does not exist on pypi anymore, probably it was deleted. I couldn't find any other source for it, so there seems to be no solution to install this dependency.
I could not find a reference to mailgw in the sourcecode, so you can try to download the source code from https://github.com/ramon-victor/freegpt-webui and delete that dependency from the requirements.txt. Then run pip install . in the source directory.

I tried it, but even if it was installed, it couldn't be used at all. Well, I wasted two days. I should have watched the issue page before installing...
